How to remove item from local storage in python aggrid from streamlit
I have an aggrid grid in streamlit for python, and I added a new button to remove a local storage item:
    (
        b1,
        b2,
        b3,
        b4,
        b5,
        b6,
        b7,
        b8,
        reset_grid_button,
        spacer1
    ) = selector_container.columns([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3])

    with reset_grid_button:
        st.write('##')
        st.button(
            label="Reset Grid",
            on_click=reset_grid_button_clicked,
            key="pt_reset_grid_button"
        )

I created a JsCode object to make the local storage remove item action and set the on_click parameter of the button to it:
reset_grid_button_clicked = JsCode("""
    function(params) {
        console.log("resetColumns!");
        localStorage.removeItem('pt-ag-grid-columnstate');
        originalColumnState = localStorage.getItem('pt-ag-grid-original-columnstate');
        params.columnApi.applyColumnState({state: JSON.parse(originalColumnState), applyOrder: true});
        console.log("Original ColumnState Applied!");
    }
""")

The problem is that when I push the button, I get this error:
TypeError: 'JsCode' object is not callable

How can I remove the local storage item?
